# Align form inputs in the same line

Tags: css, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

so I have this Symfony `Form` which I created, and there are these 3 inputs that are related to each other. I'm trying to align all three of them in the same line to make it looks better.
Here's my code:
the `FormType`

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TimeType;

use App\Entity\TypeParking;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class TypeParkingType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('libelle')
            ->add('tempsmax')
            ->add('jourdebut')
            ->add('jourfin')



//these three are the fields that I'm trying to put into a single line
            ->add('jourstravail_jour', TextType::class, ['property_path' => 'jourstravail[jour]'])
            ->add('jourstravail_debut', TextType::class, ['property_path' => 'jourstravail[debut]'])
            ->add('jourstravail_fin', TextType::class, ['property_path' => 'jourstravail[fin]'])


            ->add('Exception_Name', TextType::class, ['property_path' => 'exception[name]'])
            ->add('Starting_date', TextType::class, ['property_path' => 'exception[datedebut]'])
            ->add('Ending_date', TextType::class, ['property_path' => 'exception[datefin]'])
            ->add('Starting_time', TextType::class, ['property_path' => 'exception[heuredebut]'])
            ->add('Ending_time', TextType::class, ['property_path' => 'exception[heurefin]'])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => TypeParking::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

and here's my _form.html.twig file

```
{{ form_start(form) }}

    {{ form_row(form.libelle, { 'label': 'Label' }) }}
    {{ form_row(form.tempsmax, { 'label': 'Max Time' }) }}
    {{ form_row(form.jourdebut, { 'label': 'Start Date' }) }}
    {{ form_row(form.jourfin, { 'label': 'Ending Date' }) }}

    <h3>these are the fields</h3>
    {{ form_row(form.jourstravail_jour, { 'label': 'Day' }) }}
    {{ form_row(form.jourstravail_debut, { 'label': 'start' }) }}
    {{ form_row(form.jourstravail_fin, { 'label': 'end' }) }}

    <h3>Exception</h3>
    {{ form_row(form.Exception_Name, { 'label': 'Exception Name' }) }}
    {{ form_row(form.Starting_date, { 'label': 'Starting Date' }) }}
    {{ form_row(form.Ending_date, { 'label': 'Ending Date' }) }}
    {{ form_row(form.Starting_time, { 'label': 'Starting Time' }) }}
    {{ form_row(form.Ending_time, { 'label': 'Ending Time' }) }}




    <button class="btn">{{ button_label|default('Save') }}</button>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

The fields that I'm trying to format are `jourstravail_jour`, `jourstravail_debut` and `jourstravail_fin`

Comment: Why not using some sort as CSS "framework" like Bootstrap, Fomantic-ui, Foundation (or others, there are tons of them) ? Almost all of them have CSS classes to do what you want and even more.

Comment: I do actually I'm using bootstrap, It's just that I didn't know how to use it when it comes to dealing with Symfony Forms.

Comment: You can use it "normally", by using `form_label()` and `form_widget`(not sure about this one) and wrap them with Bootstrap classes. or you can customize the `form_row` behaviour : https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html and include your classes in your own form template.

Comment: Ah it worked, thanks a lot, It was so much simpler than I thought.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is an answer based on my comments that seemed to help you, so you can tag your questions as answered.

You can use it "normally", by using `form_label()` and `form_widget()`(not sure about this one) and wrap them with Bootstrap classes.

Or you can customize the [`form_row()` behaviour](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html)  and include your classes in your own form templates.